# Synchronize SVN empty Resources

Tags: svn, subclipse, synchronize

I have installed subclipse plugin in my Eclipse Kepler. When I'm trying to synchronize all projects, available resource appears empty.

How i can resolve this?

[image: Empty Resources]

Comment: Do you have any project checked out in your Eclipse Workspace? Or checked out via another client such TortoiseSVN?

Answer (score 3):

My solution was to import all projects again after instalation of subclipse.
Now appears all normal.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to sync your existing projects with svn. i.e. Eclipse needs to understand that you are using projects of the svn.. To solve the issue first share your project to svn then try to sync your projects..